# PDO/PHP LoginScript ending in error 500 using MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been trying for a while now to get my loginscript working and i can't seem to find the issue, either im just blind or there's something else going on here.

It doesn't matter if i input the correct credentials or not into the form, i still end up getting a lovely error 500.

Any ideas?

The DB connect funtion:

```
function db_connect() {
```

if i move this column-->

```
    $server = 'localhost';
    $uname = 'root';
    $passw = 'password';
    $datab = 'database';

    /* check connection */
    try{
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$datab;", $uname, $passw);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die( "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
```

<---

```
   return $conn; /added this as suggested, still returns NULL.
}
```

The login file:

```
include('../lib/functions.php'); //This is correct!
db_connect();
```

<-- HERE, it works -->

Earlier had an issue where my password hash during register was faulty, so `password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['passw'])`had no effect, always returning false even with correct input.

```
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT uname,passw FROM users WHERE uname = :user AND passw = :pass');
    $records->bindparam(':user', $_POST['username']);
    $records->bindparam(':pass', $_POST['password']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['passw']) && $_POST['username'] == $results['uname']) //Also tried removing the &&-->username area incase two and statements were wrong without any luck {
        die('It works!');
    } else  {
        die('OR NOT!');
    }

endif;
```

Comment: Errorcode 500 means server error. Eg. in your PHP script. Check the php's error log file. (see php.ini)

Comment: `db_connect()` doesn't return anything!!

Comment: First thing you _always_ have to do when you get some unexpected error in your php code: take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can actually simply _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_ or ask here.

Comment: function `db_connect()` defines `$conn` in it's own scope. Outside this function `$conn` is __NULL__.

Comment: Yes, that is correct @u_mulder I've moved it from the function into the if statement in the loginfile, then it works to 50%, the if statement where it checks if the user is registred in the DB returns false even if i input the correct credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `db_connect()` function defines `$conn` in it's own scope. So, variable `$conn` is local. And after `db_connect()` ends executing `$conn` just disappears.

Outside this function `$conn` is simply **NULL**.

Return `$conn` to outer scope from your function:

```
function db_connect() {
    $server = 'localhost';
    $uname = 'root';
    $passw = 'password';
    $datab = 'database';

    /* check connection */
    try{
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$datab;", $uname, $passw);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die( "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    }

    return $conn;    // here
}
```

And in your script:

```
include('../lib/functions.php'); //This is correct!
$conn = db_connect();
// other codes
```

Comment: I've tried this, `$conn` is still null. but when i move the code from the function and put it straight into the login file it works to 50%, even if i input the right credentials it return false.

Comment: Now i've solved the credential part, but for some reason `$conn` still returns null when used inside the function. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see this line `$conn = db_connect();`